# Ember.js Mocha tests failing randomly with async code

Tags: testing, ember.js, promise, mocha.js

I’m writing tests for an Ember.js application with Mocha. I use the ember-mocha-adapter from Teddy Zeenny.

As soon as a promise is involved, the tests fail randomly. I usually get this error:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot defer readiness since the `ready()` hook has already been called.
```

Here is a [JS Bin testcase](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nusewoqi/8/edit?js,output). It contains 10 times the same test and usually fails (tested with Firefox and Chromium).

The same tests run fine with QUnit (maybe by chance :)) ([JS Bin testcase](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/famajapa/3/edit?js,output)). How can I make this work with Mocha? I tried wrapping the promise in an Ember.run() call, but it doesn’t solve the problem.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630048/ember-mocha-tests-fail-when-async-using-ember-mocha-adapter) about the same problem, but the corrected JS Bin proposed by Teddy Zeenny also fails for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems with the code:

1. It should not call mocha.setup(), as is now explained in the README.
2. The function calls to setup Ember.js for testing should happen outside any Mocha callback, not in `before()`.
3. `mocha.run()` should be called like this:

   ```
   Ember.$(function() {
     mocha.run();
   });
   ```

Here is the fixed [JS Bin testcase](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nusewoqi/16/edit?js,output).

Teddy Zeenny found the solution to this problem in [teddyzeenny/ember-mocha-adapter#18](https://github.com/teddyzeenny/ember-mocha-adapter/issues/18).

Answer (score 0):

Really the only reason the qunit is working and mocha isn't is because you're running reset before each test vs after each test.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nusewoqi/4/edit

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake converting the tests to QUnit, thanks for pointing this out. I meant to call App.reset() after the tests. I corrected the [QUnit testcase](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/famajapa/3/edit?js,output) to use teardown() instead of setup() and it still works. Anyway, with your changes it still fails for me (with the Assertion Failed error message for the first test case) :(.

Comment: gotcha, it was working for me every time in chrome, I didn't even try firefox, but it does seem more sporadic there